# About listeners in Delegation-Event-Model pattern

Tags: java

Hi I have a question about using this pattern. When making listeners should the names of the methods be what the name of the method in the model are that triggered the event? Such as:

(Trivial example that shows what I mean)
**Model:**

```
public void setName(String name) {...}
public void setAge(int age) {...}
```

**Listener**

```
void nameChanged(TheEventObject event);
void ageChanged(TheEventObject event);
```

Or should this be:

```
void personChanged(The EventObject event);
```

Where the person-prefix is the name of the Model class.

To recap should the methods in the interface be for each specific method that changed some value in the model, or should it be just one that says "Hey, model changed"?

Comment: That depends on what `TheEventObject` contains.  Does it have a way to determine what changed?

Comment: At this momement I have made listener-method for each method that changes something in the model. But if I just have one general model-has-changed method, would it be ok to just add an instance variable or something that indicated what changed? And which of these "methods" are most frequently used.

Comment: Hoi, it's a design decision, i think. If you see the "person" object as one complex source, i would stick to personChanged(...); Otherwise the person is just a data container and more detailed listeners might be wise, since you might not care about the "whole person" at all. ... Just my thoughts ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that easier for future is to created in the another way in some parent abstract class that each been will be delivered, you could create a instance of some class that will manage the notification kind of property change manager(observer) that would fire a event after property change.

```
firePropertyChange("properyName", newValue, oldValue);
```

To support this you could use the `java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent`

Base interface for a property change observer:

```
void fireBeforePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object currentValue, Object newValue) throws PropertyChangeException;
void removeBeforePropertyChangeListener(BeforePropertyChangeListener beforePropertyChangeListener);
Enumeration<BeforePropertyChangeListener> getBegorePropertyChangeListeners();
```